# Group and sum data by common prefix from column value with different length prefixes and inconsistent delimiters in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I am new to using Python and Pandas, but have been trying to automate some of the data cleaning/merging for reports of mine. 
So far I've had success in building up the combined file of all information I need to feed into my reporting summary but have 
gotten stuck with grouping and merging data with matching prefixes.

I have a data set that is structured similar to this in a pandas dataframe:

```
Company_Num     Company_Name                2019_Amt    2020_Amt    Code    Flag    Manager

1               ABC Company Ltd             2000        400         A       Y       John
1               ABC Company Ltd             2000        400         A       Y       John
2               DEFGHIJ Company (London)    480         100         B       N       James
3               DEFGHIJ Company (Bristol)   600         700         B       N       James
4               DEFGHIJ Company (York)      1500        1000        B       N       James       
5               KLM Services                9000        7000        A       Y       Jane   
6               NOPQ Industries             300         400         C       Y       Jen   
7               NOPQ Industries - London    7000        8000        C       Y       Jen
```

I'm wanting to get a summary set of data where there are no duplicates in my data and 
instead of having rows for each office I have one summarised value for each company. Ultimately
with a dataframe like:

```
Company_Name            2019_Amt    2020_Amt    Code    Flag
ABC Company Ltd         2000        400         A       Y   
DEFGHIJ Company         2580        1800        B       N   
KLM Services            9000        7000        A       Y   
NOPQ Industries         7300        8400        C       Y
```

So far I have managed to drop the duplicates using:

`df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Company_Num', 'Company_Name', 'Code', '2019_Amt', '2020_Amt'])`

With the resulting table:

```
Company_Num     Company_Name                2019_Amt    2020_Amt    Code    Flag    Manager
1               ABC Company Ltd             2000        400         A       Y       John
2               DEFGHIJ Company (London)    480         100         B       N       James
3               DEFGHIJ Company (Bristol)   600         700         B       N       James
4               DEFGHIJ Company (York)      1500        1000        B       N       James       
5               KLM Services                9000        7000        A       Y       Jane
6               NOPQ Industries             300         400         C       Y       Jen   
7               NOPQ Industries - London    7000        8000        C       Y       Jen
```

The solution that I have tried is to substring the first 9 characters of each company name and use a groupby 
and sum on those, but that leaves me with the column being saved as the substring. This has also dropped the 
columns Code and Flag from my dataframe, leaving me with table like this:

```
df['SubString_Company_Name'] = df['Company_Name'].str.slice(0,9)
df.groupby([df.SubString_Company_Name]).sum().reset_index()
```

```
SubString_Company_Name    2019_Amt    2020_Amt    
ABC Compa                 2000        400
DEFGHIJ C                 2580        1800   
KLM Servi                 9000        7000
NOPQ Indu                 7300        8400
```

I have tried to use the os.path.commonprefix function to get the company names, but can't find a way to use it in a dataframe, 
and for multiple values. My understanding is it will look at the list as a whole and return the longest common prefix of the 
whole list which wouldn't work. I have also considered extracting all duplicate substrings into new dataframes and summing 
and renaming there before merging back into one data set, but I'm not sure if that would work. The solutions I've found online 
have been centred around uniform data where lambda can be used with a delimiter or the prefix is always the same size, whereas 
my data is not uniform and the prefixes are varying sizes.

My data is changed every month and so I want to design a dynamic solution that isn't relying on substrings since I could run into 
issues with only taking 9 characters. My final consideration is to extract the SubString_Company_Name
into a list, convert that to the os.path.commonprefix of the Company_Name and then save the unique commonprefix value of each
Company_Name into a new list and for each item in that list create a new summary table. But I don't know if this would work and 
I want to know if there's a better or more efficient way of doing this before trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) after dropping duplicates and use [`series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with the first string from the split `.str[0]` as the grouper:

```
d= {'Company_Name':'first','2019_Amt':'sum','2019_Amt':'sum',
               '2020_Amt':'sum','Code':'first','Flag':'first'}
grouper = df['Company_Name'].str.split().str[0]

out = df.drop_duplicates().groupby(grouper).agg(d).reset_index(drop=True)
print(out)
```

---

```
               Company_Name  2019_Amt  2020_Amt Code Flag
0           ABC Company Ltd      2000       400    A    Y
1  DEFGHIJ Company (London)      2580      1800    B    N
2              KLM Services      9000      7000    A    Y
3           NOPQ Industries      7300      8400    C    Y
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the drop_duplicates code from my question and removed it in this code because with my actual data that I'm using it came up summing the duplicates. But the rest of it worked perfectly. Follow up question to this would be can this be modified to drop the (London) bit from the combination? That is one of my main concerns because for some it's companies as a whole and some it's only tracking specific offices and would like to differentiate.

Comment: @Syd Glad it helped  , is there a set pattern where the city names occur in the column?

Comment: There isn't a pattern, but your answer gave me a good direction on where to go with this problem. I'll need to find the common substring between each group and pass that into a list as the grouper values.